# All libs in maven manifest should be included in the artifact right?

Tags: maven, jar

I'm just trying to understand if all dependencies in the pom files under maven manifest `META-INF/maven/` actually are included as part of the generated archive or not.
Example let's say I'm looking at pom file under some archive `some.jar` at this path:
`some.jar/META-INF/maven/com.sun.jersey/jersey-core/pom.xml`
Now all dependencies in this should be part of some.jar right?

Comment: Are you looking to package the jars in your pom's dependency section into this some.jar?

Comment: apologies for being little vague. Actually I'm trying to understand if maven uses some sort of intelligence to ensure everything it adds in as manifest info in META-INT/maven is actually bundled with the jar or it just dumps all pom files of all direct and transitive dependencies irrespective of whether they are packaged with the artifact produced or not.